# SQL how to find out which table the data is located

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I have three tables `Pub`, `Boo`, `Per`.

`Boo.num` is a reference to `Pub.serial`

`Per.num` is a reference to `Pub.serial` (means `Pub` has info about both of them)

I would like to know a row on `Pub` belongs to `Per` or `Boo`.

**How can I do this?**

*(I just need an additional field to have 0 or another number to determine which one of these the data belongs to)*

Think of it as Pub is parent of both Boo and Per and those tables are types of Pub.

Comment: Its called relationship. Go google primary key foreign key

Comment: Imagine people post their code on SO... just imagine.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO that would be a joyous day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you are looking for, but it's worth a try:

```
select Pub.serial,
    (select count(*) from Boo where Boo.num = Pub.serial) as Boo_Count,
    (select count(*) from Per where Per.num = Pub.serial) as Per_Count
From Pub
Order by Pub.serial
```

Comment: Thank you very much man. I thought I tried this but my version didn't work. This solved it. Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You want to

```
SELECT Boo.num, per.num
FROM Pub
LEFT JOIN Boo ON Pub.serial=Boo.num
LEFT JOIN Per ON Pub.serial=Per.num
```

And see which of them has data.

Comment: That returns zero result!!